# Calculating the value of a field based on the difference between the values of another field in two adjacent positions using haskell

Tags: list, haskell, map-function

I have a list of custom data objects which track an increasing total value on a daily basis using one field `total`. Another field in the custom data type is the value `new`. Using a csv file I have read in the values for `date` and `total` and am trying to calculate and set the values for `new` from these values.

```
data item = Item{
    date :: Day,
    total :: Int,
    new :: Int
}
```

### Before

| date | total | new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 03/01/2021 | 6 | 0 |
| 04/01/2021 | 15 | 0 |

### After

| date | total | new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 2 |
| 03/01/2021 | 6 | 4 |
| 04/01/2021 | 15 | 9 |

My understanding is that in haskell I should be trying to avoid the use of `for` loops which iterate over a list until the final row is reached, for example using a loop control which terminates upon reaching a value equal to the length of the list.

Instead I have tried to create a function which assigns the value of new which can used with `map` to update each item in the list. My problem is that such a function requires access to both the item being updated, as well as the previous item's value for `total` and I'm unsure how to implement this in haskell.

```
--Set daily values by mapping single update function across list
calcNew:: [Item] -> Int -> [Item]
calcNew items = map updateOneItem items 

-- takes an item and a value to fill the new field
updateOneItem :: Item -> Int -> Item
updateOneItem item x = Item date item total item x
```

Is it possible to populate that value while using `map`? If not, is a recursive solution required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by zipping the input list with itself, shifted by one step.

Assuming you have a list of items already populated with `total` values, which you want to update to contain the correct `new` values (building an updated copy of course),

```
type Day = Int

data Item = Item{    -- data Item, NB
    date :: Day,
    total :: Int,
    new :: Int
} deriving Show

calcNews :: [Item] -> [Item]
calcNews [] = []
calcNews totalsOK@(t:ts) = t : zipWith f ts totalsOK
  where
  f this prev = this{ new = total this - total prev }
```

This gives us

```
> calcNews [Item 1 0 0, Item 2 2 0, Item 3 5 0, Item 4 10 0]
[Item {date = 1, total = 0, new = 0},Item {date = 2, total = 2, new = 2},
 Item {date = 3, total = 5,new = 3},Item {date = 4, total = 10, new = 5}]
```

Of course `zipWith f x y == map (\(a,b) -> f a b) $ zip x y`, as we saw in your previous question, so `zipWith` is like a *binary* `map`.

*Sometimes* (though not here) we might need access to the previously calculated value as well, to calculate the next value. To arrange for that we can create the result by zipping the input with the shifted version of the *result* itself:

```
calcNews2 :: [Item] -> [Item]
calcNews2 [] = []
calcNews2 (t:totalsOK) = newsOK
  where
  newsOK = t : zipWith f totalsOK newsOK
  f tot nw = tot{ new = total tot - total nw }
```

Comment: Fantastic solution, thank you. Can you explain appending OK to the list names? Is this simply to distinguish the lists from the fields in `Item`? Is this Haskell best practice or personal preference?

Comment: you're welcome. no, it's just something I did for this specific question. the totalsOK variable has Items in it with the "total" fields which are correct ("OK"), but not the "new" fields. the "newsOK" variable refers to the list of Items with the  fields - both total and new - which are correct. (because initially, the "new" fields are initialized as 0s, so initially are all incorrect). just a mental note in the names instead of in the comments. a mnemonic. :)